# UINavigationItem on destination scene disappears when segue style changed from Push to Modal

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

With a seque between `UINavigationController` scenes, why does changing a seque style from `Push` to `Modal` cause the `UINavigationItem` on the destination scene to disappear from the IB and the built app? Interestingly, the `UINavigationItem` is still in the IB hierarchy.

How do I get a Modal seque with the `UINNavigationItem` still visible on the destination scene? I'm trying to do something simple-seeming like the edit functionality in the iPhone Contacts app. There you have a Modal that comes up on contact edit, and you can navigate back to a contact detail when finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any view controller can have a navigation item, but it only shows up if your view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. Modal view controllers don't inherit the navigation controllers of the view controller that presented them -- essentially, they represent a branch in your user's path through the app, rather than an extension of the navigation stack they came from.

If you want the stuff a navigation controller provides in your modal view controller, embed that VC in a navigation controller, and present that navigation controller modally.

(Or if you just want a navigation bar to appear at the top of the view, and don't care about the other stuff you get from `UINavigationController`, you can drop a `UINavigationBar` (Navigation Bar in the Object Library) into the view in IB.)

Comment: Exciting! "If you want the stuff a navigation controller provides in your modal view controller, embed that VC in a navigation controller, and present that navigation controller modally." <-- "Present a navigation controller modally" sort of blows my mind a bit.

Comment: Because, when you "present a Navigation Controller modally," you're presenting all of the VCs on its stack, too, right?

Comment: Sort of... you're presenting the navigation controller, so whatever VC it shows is what appears in the modal "window". And each modal presentation can have its own navigation stack. You can see this in Apple apps: you can drill down through your mailboxes to threads to messages in Mail, and at any point in that navigation stack you can start a new message, which presents a modal VC, and in the compose view you can press a + button to add addressees from your Contacts -- that's another modal VC, containing a nav controller that lets you drill down to a contact and choose their email address.

Answer (score 1):

If you're presenting a modal view controller, it won't have the navigation bar that was present in the presenting controller (assuming that one is embedded in a navigation controller). The top bar in the Contacts app is probably a `UIToolbar` ("Toolbar" in the Objects Library). You can drag one of those into your controller, and add bar button items to it in IB. There are a  lot of different styles for these buttons that you can choose from, including "Done" and "Cancel".

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. Is this because, logically, a Modal seque isn't a "navigation" event?

Comment: @dimadima, I guess it depends on how you define "navigation". In the broader sense, it might be, but it's not using the navigation controller, so in that sense, it's not.